# Automorphisms of an Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I need to find the automorphisms of the following algebra. An element of the algebra is given by the vector $\left(x_{0},x_{1},x_{2};\lambda_{0},\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}\right)$ where $x_i$ are Quaternions and $\lambda_{i}$ are reals and the product is given by

$$ \left(x_{0},x_{1},x_{2};\lambda_{0},\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}\right)\circ\left(y_{0},y_{1},y_{2};\mu_{0},\mu_{1},\mu_{2}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}}{2}y_{0}+\frac{\mu_{1}+\mu_{2}}{2}x_{0}+x_{1}*y_{2}+y_{1}*x_{2}\\
\frac{\lambda_{0}+\lambda_{2}}{2}y_{1}+\frac{\mu_{0}+\mu_{2}}{2}x_{1}+x_{2}*y_{0}+y_{2}*x_{0}\\
\frac{\lambda_{0}+\lambda_{1}}{2}y_{2}+\frac{\mu_{0}+\mu_{1}}{2}x_{2}+x_{0}*y_{1}+y_{0}*x_{1}\\
\lambda_{0}\mu_{0}+\left\langle x_{1},y_{1}\right\rangle +\left\langle x_{2},y_{2}\right\rangle \\
\lambda_{1}\mu_{1}+\left\langle x_{0},y_{0}\right\rangle +\left\langle x_{2},y_{2}\right\rangle \\
\lambda_{2}\mu_{2}+\left\langle x_{0},y_{0}\right\rangle +\left\langle x_{1},y_{1}\right\rangle 
\end{array}\right)$$
and $x*y$ is the quaternionic product and $\left\langle x,y\right\rangle$ is the inner product of two quaternions.
I tried to impose
$$\varphi\left(\left(x_{\nu};\lambda_{\nu}\right)\circ\left(y_{\eta};\mu_{\eta}\right)\right)=\varphi\left(x_{\nu};\lambda_{\nu}\right)\circ\varphi\left(y_{\eta};\mu_{\eta}\right)$$
But I didn't get too much. Do you have any idea?

P.s. Bonus Question: Would it change something if I had Octonions instead of Quaternions?

Comment: Is ⟨x1,y1⟩ the inner product of the two quaternions, i.e. the sum of the four products of corresponding components of the two quaternions?

Comment: yes you're right I will edit

Comment: One more question: Has it been checked that (with your $\circ$ product) this is indeed an algebra? [If it comes from some known source please cite.]

Comment: More generally, is it supposed to come from a certain context? Does it have some interpretation? This looks highly arbitrary as it is formulated.

Comment: It is indeed an algebra, it comes from a specific article by Elduque, it is not arbitrary but the context is not relevant and would just point to the wrong direction

Comment: Are the $\mu_1$ and $y_1$ in the second row supposed to be respectively $\mu_0$ and $y_0$? (It would make it more symmetric, and in particular at the very least there would be a cyclic automorphism of order $3$.)

Comment: @CaptainLama you are definitely right... sorry I changed the indices and left those two out... And indeed the cyclic automorphism of order three, along with the automorphisms of the field of quaternions is the only thing I came up with...

Comment: Yes, it's quite clear that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times PGL_1(\mathbb{H})$ is a subgroup of the automorphism group, I'm trying to see if I can prove it's the whole group. Just to be sure that there is no mistake in the formula, the algebra is commutative and with unit, but not associative, right?

Comment: @CaptainLama totally right!

Comment: Ok, I have to say I'm having a bit of fun with this question, I should be able to write a full answer tomorrow.

Comment: @CaptainLama go for it! :) :) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have to say it was quite fun (and a very good source of procrastination) to figure out a bit of structure of this algebra just working with the formula, with no idea where it comes from (but I would be curious to look into that). This answer is very long, for a tl;dr just go the the "Theorem"; basically all automorphisms come from automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$ and from a cyclic symmetry.

### Notations and terminology

Let us fix some notation first. Let $A$ be the above algebra, with its product $x\circ y$ as described in the question. I will write
$$A = \left( \bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}}Q_i \right)\oplus \mathbb{R}^3$$
where each $Q_i$ is a copy (as a vector space) of the Hamilton quaternions $\mathbb{H}$. I will write $N(q)$ for the *norm* of a quaternion $q\in \mathbb{H}$, ie $N(q)=\langle q,q\rangle$.

I will also similarly decompose
$$\mathbb{R}^3 = \bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}}D_i$$
where $D_i$ is a copy of $\mathbb{R}$. For each $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, this gives us projections
$$\pi_i: A\to \mathbb{H},\quad \eta_i: A\to \mathbb{R}$$
such that if $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2; \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in A$ then $x_i=\pi_i(x)$ and $\lambda_i=\eta_i(x)$, seeing the indices $0$, $1$, and $2$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ rather than just integers (the reason is that there is a clear cyclic symmetry in the algebra, we'll come back to it).

Conversely, we have injections
$$\omega_i: \mathbb{H}\to A,\quad \theta_i: \mathbb{R}\to A$$
and I will also write $\xi_i = \theta_i(1)$. (Just to be clear, this means for instance $\omega_0(q)=(q,0,0;0,0,0)$ and $\xi_1 = (0,0,0;0,1,0)$).

I will call the three quaternions $\pi_i(x)$ the *quaternionic components* of $x\in A$, and $\eta_i(x)$ its *scalar components*. I will say that an element is *proper* when all three quaternionic components are non-zero; otherwise it is improper. I will also say that an element $x\in A$ is *vectorial* when all its quaternionic components are zero, ie $x\in \mathbb{R}^3\subset A$.

The idempotents of $A$ will play a crucial role, so I fix a bit of terminology (as I'm not very familiar with non-associative algebra, I have no idea what is customary or not in this area, so this may be non-standard). Here an *idempotent* is an element $e\in A$ such that $e^2=e$; it is *non-trivial* if $e\neq 0,1$. It is *primitive* if it is non-trivial and cannot be written as a sum of two non-trivial idempotents. Two idempotents $e,e'$ are *orthogonal* when $e\circ e'=0$; since $2$ is invertible here, this is equivalent to $e+e'$ being itself idempotent. If $e\in A$ is an idempotent, consider the application $x\mapsto e\circ x$; its range, kernel and rank are called respectively the range, kernel and rank of $e$. A set of mutually orthogonal idempotents is *complete* when their sum is the unit element of $A$.

### Basic facts

It is easy to see from the definition that $A$ is indeed an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra in the weak sense that its product is $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear. It is also not difficult to notice that it is commutative, and that $\xi:=\xi_0+\xi_1+\xi_2=(0,0,0;1,1,1)$ is a unit element. The vectorial part $\mathbb{R}^3\subset A$ has its usual algebra structure as a direct product of three copies of the field $\mathbb{R}$.

We may rewrite the definition of the product by saying that it is commutative and satisfies these rules:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\xi_i\circ \xi_j & = & \delta_{i,j} \xi_i \\
\xi_i\circ \omega_i(q) & = & 0 \\
\xi_i \circ \omega_j(q) & = & \frac{1}{2}\omega_j(q) \text{ if $i\neq j$} \\
\omega_i(q)\circ \omega_i(q') & = & \langle q,q'\rangle(\xi_{i+1}+\xi_{i+2})\\
\omega_i(q)\circ \omega_{i+1}(q') & = & \omega_{i+2}(qq').
\end{eqnarray*}$$

On the other hand, $A$ is *not* associative, which makes things a little unfamiliar for most people. For instance, using the above rules, if $i\neq j\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$(\xi_i\circ \xi_i)\circ \omega_j(q) = \xi_i\circ \omega_j(q) = \frac{1}{2}\omega_j(q)$$
but
$$\xi_i\circ (\xi_i\circ \omega_j(q)) = \xi_i\circ \left(\frac{1}{2}\omega_j(q)\right) = \frac{1}{4}\omega_j(q).$$
Actually, this shows that $A$ is not even alternative (so it's way worse than the octonions).

> **Lemma 1:** Let $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Then the range of $\xi_i$ is $Q_{i+1}\oplus Q_{i+2}\oplus D_i$, and its kernel is $Q_i\oplus D_{i+1}\oplus D_{i+2}$. In particular, it has rank $9$.

*Proof of Lemma 1:* That follows straight from the formulas.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

### Automorphisms

We come to the crucial question of automorphisms. There are two kinds of automorphisms of $A$ which are easy to spot: first, for any automorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{H}$, we get an induced automorphism $\varphi_*: A\to A$ given by
$$\varphi_*(x_0,x_1,x_2; \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = (\varphi(x_0),\varphi(x_1),\varphi(x_2); \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2).$$
In other words, $\varphi$ acts on each $Q_i$ and leaves $\mathbb{R}^3$ unaffected. It is easy to see on the formula for the product that this does define an automorphism of $A$; the key point is that any automorphism of $\mathbb{H}$ is an isometry: it preserves the scalar product.

Another source of automorphisms is that there is a clear cyclic symmetry in the formula: one may easily check that $\sigma: A\to A$ defined by
$$\sigma(x_0,x_1,x_2; \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = (x_2,x_0,x_1; \lambda_2,\lambda_0,\lambda_1)$$
is an automorphism. In otherwords, $\sigma$ sends $Q_i$ (resp. $D_i$) identically to $Q_{i+1}$ (resp. $D_{i+1}$).

Combining these two observations, we get that $\operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{H})$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are two subgroups of $\operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{R}(A)$. (Recall that all automorphisms of $\mathbb{H}$ are inner, and therefore $\operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{R}(\mathbb{H})\simeq PGL_1(\mathbb{H}) = \mathbb{H}^\times/\mathbb{R}^\times$.) Actually since these actions clearly commute, we get that
$$\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times PGL_1(\mathbb{H}) \subset \operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{R}(A).$$

The main point of this answer is:

> **Theorem:** The above inclusion is an equality, and $\operatorname{Aut}_\mathbb{R}(A) = \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times PGL_1(\mathbb{H})$.

The crucial idea of my proof is to look in details into the idempotents of $A$. Precisely, the key argument is the following statement:

> **Proposition 1:** Any automorphism of $A$ must permute the set $\{\xi_0,\xi_1,\xi_2\}$.

Let us see how this statement proves the theorem:

*Proof of the theorem:* Let $\Phi\in \operatorname{Aut}_{\mathbb{R}}(A)$, and let $g\in \mathfrak{S}(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ be the permutation such that $\Phi(\xi_i)=\xi_{g(i)}$.

Using Lemma 1, we can characterize $Q_i\subset A$ as $(\xi_{i+1}\circ A)\cap (\xi_{i+2}\circ A)$, and we deduce that $\Phi(Q_i)=Q_{g(i)}$. This means there are three automorphisms $\varphi_i$ of $\mathbb{H}$ such that $\Phi(\omega_i(q))=\omega_{g(i)}(\varphi_i(q))$ for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in \mathbb{H}$.

It's not too hard to see that all three $\varphi_i$ must be equal, and that $g$ cannot be a transposition. For instance, applying $\Phi$ to the formula
$$\omega_0(q)\circ \omega_1(q') = \omega_2(qq')$$ we get
$$\omega_{g(2)}(\varphi_0(q)\varphi_1(q')) = \omega_{g(2)}(\varphi_2(qq'))$$
if $g$ permutes $0$ and $1$ in the direct order, and
$$\omega_{g(2)}(\varphi_1(q')\varphi_0(q)) = \omega_{g(2)}(\varphi_2(qq'))$$
if it permutes them in the indirect order. Taking $q'=1$ shows that $\varphi_0(q)=\varphi_2(q)$, and taking $q=1$ shows $\varphi_1(q')=\varphi_2(q')$, so $\varphi_0=\varphi_1=\varphi_2$, and we write $\varphi$ for this automorphism of $\mathbb{H}$. Then if $g$ were the transposition $(12)$ we would get
$$\varphi(q')\varphi(q)=\varphi(qq')$$
for all $q,q'\in \mathbb{H}$ which is obviously impossible. Reasoning similarly, $g$ cannot be any transposition and therefore $g$ is cyclic.

This shows that $\Phi\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times PGL_1(\mathbb{H})$, the first component being given by $g$, and the second by $\varphi_*$.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

### Special subalgebras

So to prove the theorem, it just remains to prove Proposition 1. We will actually show something much stronger, because why not, and in particular give a complete description of idempotents in $A$. Before we do that, I introduce a few special subalgebras of $A$.

For each $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, we define
$$E_i=Q_i\oplus D_{i+1}\oplus D_{i+2}.$$
It is a subalgebra of $A$, of dimension $6$, but not as an algebra with unit. It does have a unit element, namely $\xi_{i+1}+\xi_{i+2}$, but it is not the same unit as $A$.

Now consider triplets $T=(L_0,L_1,L_2)$ of lines in $\mathbb{H}$, indexed by $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. We say a triplet is *linked* if for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$L_i\circ L_{i+1}= L_{i+2}.$$
Clearly, any cyclic permutation of a linked triplet is still linked.

For any linked triplet $T$, we get a subalgebra (with unit, this time) of dimension $6$
$$E(T) = \left(\bigoplus_{i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}}\omega_i(L_i)\right)\oplus \mathbb{R}^3.$$
The condition that the triplet is linked is just what is necessary to make this stable by products.

It turns out it's not complicated to describe all possible linked triplets:

> **Lemma 2:** There are three types of linked triplets:
>
> - the *scalar triplet* $(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$;
> - the *mixed triplets* $(\mathbb{R},L,L)$, $(L,\mathbb{R},L)$ and $(L,L,\mathbb{R})$ where $L\subset \mathbb{H}_0$ is a line in *pure* quaternions;
> - the *pure triplets* $(L_0,L_1,L_2)$ where all $L_i\subset \mathbb{H}_0$ are lines of pure quaternions such that the non-zero elements of two different lines anti-commute.

To get a pure triplet, one may start with any non-zero pure quaternion $q$, then choose a non-zero pure quaternion which anti-commutes with $q'$, and define $L_0=\mathbb{R}q$, $L_1=\mathbb{R}q'$ and $L_2=\mathbb{R}qq'$. The classical example is the standard basis $q=i$, $q'=j$.

*Proof of Lemma 2:* This is all just basic quaternion computations, I leave it to the reader.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

If $x= (x_0,x_1,x_2; \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ is a proper element of some $E(T)$, then by definition for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ there is a unique $d_i\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ x_{i+1}x_{i+2} = d_ix_i. \label{def_d}\tag{0} $$
We prove two easy lemmas in this situation, that will be useful later.

> **Lemma 3:** If $T$ is scalar or pure, then for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ we have $d_{i+1}d_{i+2}=N(x_i)$. If $T$ is mixed, $d_{i+1}d_{i+2}=N(x_i)$ for the index $i$ corresponding to the scalar line in $T$, and $d_{i+1}d_{i+2}=-N(x_i)$ for the other two indices.

*Proof of Lemma 3:* According to Lemma 2, all $x_i$  either paiwise commute (when $T$ is scalar or mixed) or anti-commute (when $T$ is pure). This gives that for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$
$$d_{i+2}d_{i+1} = (x_ix_{i+1}x_{i+2}^{-1})(x_{i+2}x_ix_{i+1}^{-1})$$
equals $x_i^2$ if $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ commute, and $-x_i^2$ if they
anti-commute. When $T$ is scalar, all $x_j$ commute, and also $x_i^2=N(x_i)$, so $d_{i+1}d_{i+2} = N(x_i)$. When $T$ is pure, all $x_j$ anti-commute, but also $x_i^2=-N(x_i)$, so again $d_{i+1}d_{i+2} = N(x_i)$. When $T$ is mixed, we get $d_{i+1}d_{i+2} = x_i^2$, but that is $N(x_i)$ when $x_i$ is a scalar, and $-N(x_i)$ when $x_i$ is a pure quaternion.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

> **Lemma 4:** If all quaternionic components of $x$ have the same norm $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, then for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ we get $d_i^2=\alpha$.

*Proof of Lemma 4:* Just take the norm in the definition of $d_i$.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

### Classification of idempotents

We are now going to give a complete description of idempotents in $A$. The vectorial idempotents are obvious, they are the $\sum_{i\in X}\xi_i$ for some subset $X\subset \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. In general, for any $e = (x_0,x_1,x_2; \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, the equation $e^2=e$ is equivalent to the system of equations (for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$):
$$ (\lambda_{i+1}+\lambda_{i+2})x_i + 2x_{i+1}x_{i+2} =  x_i \label{eq_idem_quater}\tag{1}$$
and
$$ \lambda_i^2 + N(x_{i+1}) + N(x_{i+2}) = \lambda_i. \label{eq_idem_scal}\tag{2}$$

The connexion between idempotents and these special subalgebras is given by:

> **Proposition 2:** Let $e\in A$ be a non-vectorial idempotent. If $e$ is proper, then there is a unique linked tripled $T$ such that $e\in E(T)$. If $e$ is improper, then there is a unique $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ such that either $e\in E_i$ or $e=e'+\xi_i$ for a non-vectorial idempotent $e'\in E_i$.

*Proof of Proposition 2:* Let $e=(x_0,x_1,x_2; \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$. Equation \ref{eq_idem_quater} shows that $x_{i+1}x_{i+2}\in \mathbb{R}x_i$, and if $e$ is proper, this means that $e\in E(T)$ where $T=(L_0,L_1,L_2)$ with $L_i=\mathbb{R}x_i$ (which is a line since $x_i\neq 0$).

If $e$ is improper, say that $x_j=0$, then $x_{j+1}x_{j+2}=0$, so a second quaternionic component must be $0$ (but not all three, by hypothesis). Let $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ be the only index such that $x_i\neq 0$. Then by Equation \ref{eq_idem_scal}, $\lambda_i = \lambda_i^2$, so either $\lambda_i=0$ and $e\in E_i$, or $\lambda_i=1$ and $e=e'+\xi_i$ with $e'\in E_i$. Since $\xi_i\circ E_i=0$, $e'$ is also an idempotent.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

In each case, we can be more precise with what the idempotents look like.

#### Improper idempotents

> **Proposition 3:** Let $q\in \mathbb{H}^\times$. There exists an idempotent $e\in E_i$ with $\pi_i(e)=q$ if and only if $N(q)\leqslant \frac{1}{4}$. Then $\eta_{i+1}(e)$ and $\eta_{i+2}(e)$ are the two roots (in no particular order) of the polynomial $X^2-X+N(q)=0$. In particular, there is a unique such $e$ when $N(q)=\frac{1}{4}$, and two such $e$ when $N(q)<\frac{1}{4}$.

*Proof of Proposition 3:* When $e\in E_i$, Equation \ref{eq_idem_quater} gives $\lambda_{i+1}+\lambda_{i+2}=1$, and according to \ref{eq_idem_scal} they are the two roots of $X^2-X+N(q)=0$, with discriminant $\Delta=1-4N(q)$. Since we are looking for real solutions, they exist when $N(q)\leqslant \frac{1}{4}$, and they are distinct exactly when the inequality is strict.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Note that what we said mostly works when $q=0$: this method gives the two idempotents $\xi_{i+1}$ and $\xi_{i+2}$, but this time they are not the only solutions, as there are also $0$ and $\xi_{i+1}+\xi_{i+2}$.

If $e\in E_i$ is an idempotent with $\pi_i(e)=q$, then according to Proposition 3 there is also a (unique) idempotent $\overline{e}=E_i$ with $\pi_i(\overline{e})=-q$, and such that $\eta_{i+1}(\overline{e})=\eta_{i+2}(e)$ and $\eta_{i+2}(\overline{e})=\eta_{i+1}(e)$. We get $e+\overline{e}=\xi_{i+1}+\xi_{i+2}$, so $e$ and $\overline{e}$ are orthogonal.

> **Proposition 4:** Let $e\in E_i$ be a non-vectorial idempotent. Then the kernel of $e$ is $\mathbb{R}\overline{e}\oplus D_i$, and in particular $e$ has rank $13$.

*Proof of Proposition 4:* Let us assume that $i=0$ and write $e=(q,0,0;0,s,t)$. Recall from Proposition 3 that $s+t=1$ and $st=N(q)$ (in particular they are non-zero). For any $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2; \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, the equality $e\circ x=0$ is equivalent to the system
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}x_0+ \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}q & = & 0 \\
\frac{t}{2}x_1 + x_2q & = & 0 \\
\frac{s}{2}x_2 + qx_1 & = & 0 \\
s\lambda_1 + \langle q,x_0\rangle & = & 0 \\
t\lambda_2 + \langle q,x_0\rangle & = & 0 \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
From the second and third equalities, we get $x_1 = -\frac{2}{t}x_2q$ and $x_2=-\frac{2}{s}qx_1$; taking the norm and multiplying the two resulting equalities yields $N(x_1x_2) = N(x_1x_2)\frac{4}{N(q)^2}N(q)^2$, which is only possible if $x_1$ or $x_2$ is zero, and then the other one must be too.

The first equality says that $x_0=-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)q$, and replacing that in the last two equalities gives
$$ s\lambda_1 = t\lambda_2 = (\lambda_1+\lambda_2)N(q)$$
which just solves to $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)=(\lambda t,\lambda s)$ for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. All this means that
$$e=(x_0,0,0;\lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \lambda_0\xi_0 + \lambda \overline{e}.$$
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

#### Proper idempotents

> **Proposition 5:** Let $T$ be a linked triplet. If $T$ is mixed, $E(T)$ contains no proper idempotent. If $T$ is scalar or pure, then $E(T)$ contains exactly $8$ proper idempotents. Let $e\in E(T)$ be such an idempotent. Each $\pi_i(e)$ has norm $\frac{1}{12}$, which gives two choices for each $i\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, and all combinations are allowed. The $\eta_i(e)$ are all equal, and their common value is $\frac{3\pm \sqrt{3}}{6}$, with a plus sign iff $\pi_i(e)\pi_{i+1}(e)$ is negatively
> proportional to $\pi_{i+2}(e)$ (this is independent of $i$).

*Proof of Proposition 5:* Let us write $e=(x_0,x_1,x_2; \lambda_0,\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$. Recall the definition of the $d_i\in \mathbb{R}$ in \ref{def_d}. The system of three equations given by \ref{eq_idem_quater} gives a linear system to find the $\lambda_i$ in terms of the $d_i$, and we find
$$\lambda_i = \frac{1}{2}+d_i-d_{i+1}-d_{i+2}. \label{eq_lambda}\tag{3}$$
In particular, the $\lambda_i$ are entirely determined by the $x_i$. Furthermore, \ref{eq_idem_scal} says that $\lambda_i$ is a root of $X^2-X+N(x_{i+1})+N(x_{i+2})$.

If we write
$$\gamma = d_0^2+d_1^2+d_2^2,$$
then from \ref{eq_lambda} one finds
$$\lambda_i^2 = \frac{1}{4} + \gamma + (\lambda_i-\frac{1}{2}) -2d_id_{i+1}-2d_id_{i+2} +2d_{i+1}d_{i+2}. \label{eq_lambda_2}\tag{4}$$

Using Lemma 3, when $T$ is scalar or pure, Equation \ref{eq_idem_scal} becomes
$$\frac{1}{4}+\gamma+(\lambda-\frac{1}{2})-2N(x_{i+1})-2N(x_{i+2})+2N(x_i) + N(x_{i+1})+N(x_{i+2}) = \lambda_i$$
so
$$\gamma-\frac{1}{4} = N(x_{i+1})+N(x_{i+2}) -2N(x_i).$$
Since the quantity on the left is independent of $i$, comparing these three equalities shows that all three $N(x_i)$ are equal; let us call this value $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Given the equality just above, this implies that $\gamma=\frac{1}{4}$, and Lemma 4 shows that $d_i^2=\alpha$ for all $i$, so $\gamma=3\alpha$, and therefore
$$N(x_0)=N(x_1)=N(x_2)=\frac{1}{12}.$$
We also see from that all $d_i$ are $\pm\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$, the sign is independent of $i$ (as all $d_id_{i+1}$ are positive), and corresponds to whether $x_i$ is positively colinear to $x_{i+1}x_{i+2}$ (according to the very definition of $d_i$). From the formula for $\lambda_i$ we get
$$\lambda_i = \frac{1}{2}-d_{i+1} = \frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$$
with a plus sign iff $x_i$ is negatively colinear to $x_{i+1}x_{i+2}$.

Now assume that $T$ is mixed. We may assume for simplicity that the scalar line is $L_0$. This time Lemma 3 yields
$$\lambda_0^2 = \frac{1}{4} + \gamma + (\lambda_0-\frac{1}{2}) +2N(x_2) +2N(x_1) + 2N(x_0)$$
but
$$\lambda_1^2 = \frac{1}{4} + \gamma + (\lambda_1-\frac{1}{2}) -2N(x_0) +2N(x_2) - 2N(x_1)$$
and likewise
$$\lambda_2^2 = \frac{1}{4} + \gamma + (\lambda_2-\frac{1}{2}) -2N(x_0) +2N(x_1) - 2N(x_2).$$
So \ref{eq_idem_scal} becomes
$$\gamma-\frac{1}{4} = -2N(x_0)-3N(x_1)-3N(x_2)$$
and the other two:
$$\gamma - \frac{1}{4} = N(x_0) -3N(x_2) + 2N(x_1)$$
and
$$\gamma - \frac{1}{4} = N(x_0) -3N(x_1) + 2N(x_2).$$
This implies that $N(x_1)=N(x_2)$, and that $N(x_0)=-\frac{5}{3}N(x_1)$, which is of course impossible since it has to be positive.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

If $e\in E(T)$ is a proper idempotent, then we may define another idempotent $\overline{e}\in E(T)$ by making all the opposite sign choices for the quaternionic components. Then the scalar components will also have the opposite sign choices, meaning that $e+\overline{e}=\xi$.

#### Complete systems of idempotents

We can now prove without too much difficulty Proposition 1, and actually we show something much stronger:

> **Proposition 6:** The complete systems of primitive orthogonal idempotents in $A$ are exactly:
>
> - $\{\xi_0,\xi_1,\xi_2\}$;
> - $\{e,\overline{e}\}$ for any proper idempotent $e\in E(T)$;
> - $\{e,\overline{e},\xi_i\}$ for any non-vectorial idempotent $e\in E_i$.

*Proof of Proposition 6:* We look at all possibilities for pairs $\{e,e'\}$ of non-trivial orthogonal idempotents. First assume that $e$ is vectorial: $e=\sum_{i\in X}\xi_i$ for some (proper) subset $X\subset \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. If $e'$ is also vectorial then this is easy, $e'=\sum_{i\in Y}\xi_i$ with $Y$ included in the complement of $X$. If $e'$ is not vectorial, the equation $e\circ e'=0$ implies that $\pi_i(e')=0$ for all $i\not\in X$. This means that $e'$ is improper, so $e'\in E_i$ for some $i$, and we must have $X=\{i\}$, so in other words $e=\xi_i$.

Now let us assume both $e$ and $e'$ non-vectorial. There are several possibilities, using Proposition 2:

- If $e$ is improper and $e'$ proper: say that $e\in E_i$ (up to $\xi_i$), and $e'\in E(T)$. Then since $e+e'$ has at least two non-zero quaternionic components, we must have $e+e'$ proper. But then according to Proposition 5, both $e'$ and $e+e'$ have all $3$ scalar components equal, which means that $e$ must also have this property, but of course that is impossible since it has one scalar component equal to $0$ or $1$, and the other two summing to $1$ (see Proposition 3). So this configuration cannot happen.
- If $e$ and $e'$ are improper, they must have the same non-zero quaternionic component, since otherwise $e+e'$ would have exactly two non-zero quaternionic component, which is impossible. So we must have $e=f+\varepsilon \xi_i$ and $e'=f'+\varepsilon' \xi_i$ with $e=f,f'\in E_i$ and $\varepsilon,\varepsilon'\in \{0,1\}$. Then at most one of the $\varepsilon,\varepsilon'$ can be $1$, and $f$ and $f'$ are orthogonal, so as far as we are concerned we may assume $e=f$ and $e'=f'$. We must have $\pi_i(e)=-\pi_i(e')$, since otherwise $e+e'\in E_i$, but then according to Proposition 3, $\eta_{i+1}(x)+\eta_{i+2}(x)$ should be $1$ for $x$ equal to $e$, $e'$ and $e+e'$, which is impossible. So $\pi_i(e)=-\pi_i(e')$, and we must have $e'=\overline{e}$ (the other possibility for $e'$ will give $e+e'$ vectorial, but not idempotent).
- If $e$ and $e'$ are proper, then according to Proposition 5 $e+e'$ must have its three scalar components equal, and there are three possibilities for this common value: $\frac{3\pm \sqrt{3}}{3}$ or $1$. Looking at the descriptions in Propositions 3 and 5, the only way this is possible is if $e+e'$ is vectorial, and actually $e+e'=\xi$, so $e'=\overline{e}$.

In the end, we proved that the only possibilities were those allowed by the statement.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Finally, we can prove Proposition 1, and therefore the Theorem:

*Proof of Proposition 1:* Any automorphism must send a complete system of primitive orthogonal idempotents to another one, so it either permutes $\{\xi_0,\xi_1,\xi_2\}$ or sends it to some $\{e,\overline{e},\xi_i\}$. But according to Lemma 1 the $\xi_i$ all have rank $9$ while according to Proposition 4 $e$ and $\overline{e}$ have rank $13$, so they cannot be send to one another by an automorphism.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Comment: What an incredibly thorough answer!

Comment: Wow! I will check everything once more, but consider the bounty yours! :)

Comment: @Captain Lama, sorry to bother you, I'm parsing your wonderful answer :) but I have some questions... I'm not totally sure  that $\Phi\left(Q_{i}\right)=Q_{g(i)}$. Let's take a concrete case, i.e. to say $ \Phi\left(Q_{2}\right)=Q_{g\left(2\right)}$ we need to say that  $\Phi\left(\left(\xi_{0}\circ A\right)\cap\left(\xi_{1}\circ A\right)\right)=\Phi\left(\xi_{0}\circ A\right)\cap\Phi\left(\xi_{1}\circ A\right)$. Is it trivial? If it's trivial do not hesitate to tell me :)

Comment: Yes, that is true for any bijection! If $f:X\to Y$ is a bijection, and $A,B\subset X$, then $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ (of course it's not true for general functions).

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will continue to parse :) :) :)